# To measure the distance from a blob to the iris centre?

Tags: image, design-patterns, image-processing, blob

I obtained the blood vessel patterns in the eye as blobs. How do I calculate the distance from each blob to the iris center (c(1),c(2)). Also, for that I guess I need the center point of the blob. Is it logically correct to consider `testfeaturevector = [blobMeasurements.Centroid];` as the equivalent of the center of the blob ? Or should I take MajorAxislength /2 ?

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell without explaining what the "distance" is supposed to represent. Generally, I would say you should simply calculate the centroid or a blob and the iris, and get the distance between these two points. Also, what does `MajorAxisLength / 2` mean? Getting width and height of a blob and then taking the middle?  That doesn't look like a bulletproof measure, but it's certainly faster to compute than a centroid, so you might even consider this approach if you need raw speed. Maybe you could post some additional info on what you're trying to do. Eye recognition?

Comment: Yea...I'm trying to do sclera blood vessel recognition. I need to extract features such as distance from a particular blood vessel to the iris centre. MajorAxisLength is a region property in MATLAB that gets the major axis length of the particular feature selected.

Comment: I presume you are doing some sort of an "original" research, so depending on how you intend to do the recognition (neural networks, genetic algorithms, some other heuristics), you may want to try training your algorithm with different feature vectors and see which give you more confident results. I think your problem goes beyond the scope of actual programming (math.stackexchange.com might even be a better place for suggestions, but you should also have a more concrete question).